# Cosa significa "il convento non potrà passare gran che" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel racconto *L'aria della sera* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto queste parole che scrive la madre de l'io narrante in un biglietto:

> «Se non hai terrore di una giornata da vecchi, – mi diceva nel suo breve biglietto, – datti pena di ricordarti che a ventisei chilometri scarsi dalla tua pensione di studente c’è ancora la casa tua e di tua madre. Caso mai tu te ne fossi scordato in questi anni... Tengo però ad avvertirti che **il convento non potrà passare gran che**: e se troverai modo di rallegrarti lo stesso di una giornata del genere, allora, il mio povero caro, sarò proprio costretta a concludere che il tuo lunario è di tutta Quaresima. Né piú né meno che il mio».

La mia domanda è sul  senso dell'espressione "il convento non potrà passare gran che" in questo brano. Mi chiedo, e vi chiedo, se il suo significato è più o meno quello che si spiega alla [voce "convento" del dizionario di modi di dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/convento.shtml), cioè che il cibo che c'è in quella casa è scarso o di cattiva qualità e l'io narrante dovrà accontentarsi con questo. È possibile usare l'espressione "il convento passa" in questo senso figurato senza adoperare esattamente le frasi fatte "prendere quel che passa il convento" o "mangiare quel che passa il convento", che sono quelle che appaiono nel dizionario? Se è così, potreste fare qualche esempio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato il significato è appunto quello da te indicato, ***[per prendere quel che passa il convento](http://www.dizy.com/it/doc/5464014444298240)***:

> Questa un'espressione idiomatica molto comune, vuol dire
>   “accontentarsi” di quello che si ha a disposizione in certe situazioni
>   o di quel che viene offerto; adattarsi a una situazione non avendo
>   altre possibilità. In particolar modo è usata con riferimento al cibo,
>   quando è carente o di qualità scadente, oppure quando si è
>   semplicemente ospiti. Molto spesso è usata in senso scherzoso, anche
>   le mamme la adottano quando i figli brontolano perché il pasto non è
>   di loro gradimento, e pronunciano questo modo di dire per intendere
>   "accontentati di quello che c'è".
>
> Ci sono diverse interpretazioni sull'origine della locuzione,
>   probabilmente il campo si può restringere a due versioni.
>
> Una fa riferimento alle opere di carità dei conventi che soprattutto
>   in passato cucinavano per i poveri, i quali dovevano "accontentarsi"
>   di quello che gli veniva offerto.
>
> L'altra interpretazione riguarda i monaci stessi che dovevano
>   "accontentarsi" del cibo che la "Provvidenza" gli donava e di ciò che
>   producevano loro stessi nell'orto del convento.

Detto questo dire "oggi il convento passa..." è sicuramente utilizzabile ed è un modo semiserio per informare l'interlocutore che stante la situazione si deve accontentare di ciò che è a disposizione in quel momento.

L'equivalente Inglese è un po' più tagliente:

> Beggars can't be choosers

cioè i mendicanti non possono scegliere.

Comment: "Beggars can't be choosers" lo tradurrei "i mendicanti non possono fare gli schizzinosi"

Comment: In quel caso sarebbe Beggars can't be choosy

Comment: Qual è la fonte della citazione che hai fatto?

Comment: Non capisco bene cosa vuoi dire nel paragrafo che comincia con "Detto questo...".

Comment: Come ho detto nella domanda, mi piacerebbe avere qualche esempio di uso di questa espressione che non consista in adoperare esattamente le frasi fatte "prendere quel che passa il convento" o "mangiare quel che passa il convento".

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @RiccardoDeContardi che il modo di dire inglese "Beggars can't be choosers" non è esattamente un equivalente: qui è la madre quella che avverte il figlio che il cibo che potrà offrirgli non è un gran che.

Comment: Se l'espressione sui beggars è “più tagliente” non è “equivalente”. :-) Confermo comunque che è imparentata (come anche il cavallo a cui non si guarda in bocca), ma sottolinea – come dice Riccardo – che se si riceve qualcosa gratis non si può essere schizzinosi o aver da ridire su quello che si riceve; vedi per esempio [qui](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beggars-cant-be-choosers.html).

Comment: @Charo Fonte aggiunta. Inoltre quello che voglio dire è che il "convento passa" si può utilizzare sempre con il significato di accontentarsi di qualcosa o di una situazione.

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone: il problema era che "dire" era dentro delle virgolette e per questo non capivo.

Comment: Infatti, scusa se non me ne sono accorto prima...